# Deactivate iCloud reminders

Tags: mac, icloud, macos

I keep getting reminders to subscribe to the iCloud service, but read my words: **I do not want iCloud**! Is it possible to deactivate these annoying reminders? (I'm on Mac OS El Capitan 10.11.6).

Answer (score 1):

Go to [Apple ID](https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage) and unchecking these items (if they were be selected):
[image: Apple ID]

In general, every message from Apple has an unsubscribe link, usually, at the end of a letter. Plesase, check it.

Finally, check out a message sender in your Mail app, perhaps, those messages are not from Apple, and they are just a spam.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Andrey. I haven't been clear enough: the messages I get are not mails, they are banner from top right corner, but they often interrupt the task I am in.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I misunderstood you. In `System Preferences -> Notifications` you can set alert style to `None` for System Events.